# Changing the value of a column based on current date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `Releases` with a `StartDate` and an `EndDate`, as well as a column `IsExpired` which is by default set to 0. Is there any possible way to set `IsExpired` to 1 if the current date is > `EndDate` automatically by the SQL Server? Or do I have to do it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the column to a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE Releases DROP COLUMN IsExpired;
GO

ALTER TABLE Releases ADD IsExpired AS CASE WHEN GETDATE() > EndDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Note that you cannot persist this column, due to the use of `GETDATE()`, so you won't be able to index it. As a result, if you do need to query the table is "active" rows, I would still perform the query against `EndDate`.